# Error at line 4: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly end

Tags: oracle-apex

I can't see my error.  Could you show me where I am going wrong?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_installments_info

AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF COLLECT_AMOUNT ON test_installments

FOR EACH ROW

DECLARE

    v_id number;

BEGIN

    UPDATE test_sales

    SET REST_AMOUNT = REST_AMOUNT - :NEW.COLLECT_AMOUNT,

        PAID_AMOUNT = PAID AMOUNT + :NEW.COLLECT_AMOUNT

    WHERE SALES_ID = :NEW.SALES_ID;

END;

/
```

Error at line 4: PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

Answer (score 0):

Error is in `UPDATE`s 3rd line; cColumn name isn't `PAID AMOUNT` (with a space), but `PAID_AMOUNT`. Once fixed:

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER update_installments_info
  2    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OF COLLECT_AMOUNT ON test_installments
  3    FOR EACH ROW
  4  DECLARE
  5      v_id number;
  6  BEGIN
  7      UPDATE test_sales
  8      SET REST_AMOUNT = REST_AMOUNT - :NEW.COLLECT_AMOUNT,
  9          PAID_AMOUNT = PAID_AMOUNT + :NEW.COLLECT_AMOUNT   --> here
 10      WHERE SALES_ID = :NEW.SALES_ID;
 11  END;
 12  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
```